# Hover animation not working in firefox , element not taking keyframe properties

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have a hover animation on my HTML page, it is custom. Now the HTML looks like this:

HTML:

```
<figure class="schedule-info-box">
    <a href="">
        <img src="images/gallery/schedule/1.jpg" alt="schedule image">
        <figcaption>
            <div class="caption-wrapper">
                <h4>Yin Yoga  Dessi</h4>
                <p>06:30 - 07:30</p>
            </div>
            <a href="" class="book-online">
                Cick Here For <br>
                Online Booking
            </a>
        </figcaption>
    </a>
</figure>
```

you can see the **[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/e9c7343t/)**(the fiddle doesn't recreate the problem. )

Now when I hover over the box, I basically want the following effect:

[image: The effect I want]

unfortunately the effect in FF(mozilla) breaks. I get the following instead:

[image: The effect I get]

The problem as you can see is that the top portion of the image can be seen in FF.

Now if I open my dev tools in mozilla and change the state of

```
<div class="caption-wrapper">
</div>
```

To `:hover` and then in the dev tools add the following property `height:50%` , it works just fine , I.E. that portion of the image is no longer shown. This is funny because the effect that applied to `.caption-wrapper` , is the following:

```
@keyframes expand-schedule-header {
    0% {
        width: 75%;
    }

    25% {
        width: 100%;
    }

    50% {
        left: 0;
        /*top: 0;*/
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }

    100% {
        height: 50%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 50%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
}
```

So the height applied is indeed `50%` , so why does;t this work ? , also I have `animation-fill-mode:` set to `both;`:

```
.schedule-info-box:hover .caption-wrapper {
    -webkit-animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    -o-animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -o-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    align-items:center;
}
```

The bug can be seen **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/hover-bug/)**(works fine in chrome , not in FF).

So why am I having this issue? Why is the element not taking 50% height in FF ? Why am I seeing the image in the background?

Comment: Hi, I think you have to set height of 1st <a href></a> tag. just like you are handling a class='book-online'

Comment: @Anil figcaption is the parent and is set to width:100% and height:100% , i am aware that for % heights and widths the parent must have an explicit height and width ! :)

Comment: How can i see your code, actually your fiddle is not working properly?

Comment: @Anil , i mentioned that the fiddle does't recreate the error .. sorry about that , check the link i have to my site.

Answer (score 0):

From What I see it is caused because FireFox renders fonts different from the other browsers and as a result your element's height is shorter than expected, but since you have it set as `position:absolute` you can just set the `top:0` to the `.caption-wrapper` on `.schedule-info-box:hover`

```
.schedule-info-box:hover .caption-wrapper {
    -webkit-animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    -o-animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    animation-name: expand-schedule-header;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -o-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    align-items:center;
    top:0;
}
```